# pass a class instance from a list of instances to SQL database and bind it to a gui datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, data-binding

im trying to create a library managment system where the manager can add books or games thru the gui, im struggeling to find a way to pass the class instance to the database while keep the datagrid that shows the avalible items in the library updated.
what is the best way to do it ?
first create a class instance and then pass a list of the items to the database?
or when the new item is created, immidiatlly add it to the database and then assign the list to get items from the database, and assign the datagrid to get data from the list? if so how can i convert variables from database into an class instance?
i have created a local host database in my computer.
need to say that i have just learned sql and real amateur in it, and i did manage to get the datagrid to get the data from the database but it still empty so my main problem is how can i fill it according to the class properties and get it updated when a new item is added.

managing class

```
namespace TheLastLibrary.Classes
{
    public class MainLibrary
    {
       public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
        SqlService DbService;

    public MainLibrary()
    {
        //DbService = new SqlService();
        //DbService.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LibraryTable");
        //DbService._connection.Open();
        //DbService._reader = DbService._cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //DbService._dataTable.Load(DbService._reader);
        //DbService._connection.Close();
    }

    public void AddBook(string name, string description, double price, int discount, int minimumAge,  int quantity, BooksGenres b, string author)
    {
        Items.Add(new Book(name, description, price, discount, minimumAge, quantity, b, author));
        BookToDb(name);
    }
    public void AddGame(string name, string description, double price, int discount, int minimumAge, int quantity, GamesGenres g)
    {
        Items.Add(new Game(name, description, price, discount, minimumAge, quantity, g));
    }

     public List<Item> GetItems()
    {
        return Items;
    }

     void UpdateName(Item i, string NewName)
    {
        i.Name = NewName;
    }
     void UpdatePrice(Item i, double NewPrice)
    {
        i.Price = NewPrice;
    }
     void UpdateDiscount(Item i, int NewDiscount)
    {
        i.Discount = NewDiscount;
    }
     void UpdateQuantity(Item i, int NewQuantity)
    {
        i.Quantity = NewQuantity;
    }


     Item SearchByName(string name)
    {
        foreach (Item i in Items)
        {
            if (i == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if (i.Name == name) return i;
        }
        return null;
    }
     Item SearchById(int id)
    {
        foreach (Item i in Items)
        {
            if (i == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if (i.Id == id) return i;
        }
        return null;
    }

     Item SearchByPriceRange(int min, int max)
    {
        foreach (Item i in Items)
        {
            if (i == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if (i.Price <= max && i.Price >= min) return i;
        }
        return null;
    }
     Item SearchByMinimumAge(int min)
    {
        foreach (Item i in Items)
        {
            if (i == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if (i.MinimumAge <= min && i.Price >= min) return i;
        }
        return null;
    }

     Item SearchByGenre(string genre)
    {
        foreach (Item i in Items)
        {
            if (i == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if (i.Genre == genre) return i;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void BookToDb(string name)
    {
        Book B = (Book)SearchByName(name);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Book).GetProperties())
        {
            foreach(DataColumn Dc in DbService._dataTable.Columns)
            {
                if (Dc.ColumnName == prop.Name)
                {
                    DbService._connection.Open();
                    DbService.SqlQuery($"INSERT INTO LibraryTable ({Dc.ColumnName}) VALUES {prop.GetValue(B)}");
                    DbService._connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

trying to pass instance to data base according to properties , without sucess

```
}
```

sql service

```
 internal class SqlService
{
    public SqlConnection _connection { get;}
    public SqlCommand _cmd;
    private SqlDataAdapter _adapter;
    public SqlDataReader _reader { get; set; }
    public DataTable _dataTable { get; set; }

    public SqlService()
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-9BRI5GA;Initial Catalog=LibraryDb;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LibraryTable");
        _connection.Open();
        _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader();
        _dataTable.Load(_reader);
        _connection.Close();
    }

    public void SqlQuery(string QueryText)
    {
        _cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryText, _connection);
    }

    public DataTable QueryEx()
    {
        _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        _dataTable = new DataTable();
        _adapter.Fill(_dataTable);
        return _dataTable;
    }
     public void NonQueryEx()
    {
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    //public bool InsertBulkRecords<T>(List<T> records)
    //{
    //    bool Inserted = false;
    //    return Inserted;
    //}

    //public DataTable GetTable<T>(List<T> records)
    //{
    //    var type = typeof(T);

    //    return _dataTable;
    //}
}
```

}

Comment: you need to explore a few keywords on google. `dapper` `table-valued parameter`

Comment: What you are describing is exactly what entity framework is designed to handle.

Comment: You can't pass instances to a database. You send data to a database using SQL or a dialect. You can use a sort of ORM library to map objects of your language to data tables. You can take a look at Microsoft's Entity Framework to wrap your database do that you can manage it completely via class instances. [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)